# Every KC space is not Katetov - KC.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A $KC$-space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be Katětov-$KC$ if there is a minimal $KC$-topology $\sigma\subseteq\tau$.

A space is $KC$ if each compact space is closed.

I know that not every $KC$ space is Katětov-$KC$, but I want a easy example to show it?

I have read "A $T_{B} $ SPACE WHICH IS NOT KATETOV $T_{B}$ 
"  by "William G. Fleissner" , but I do not understand what he meant!

Do you have any example to show that not every $KC$ space is Katětov-$KC$ except it?

Answer (score 3):

I know of one other example; perhaps you’ll find it easier to understand. It’s example $3.4$ in Chiara Baldovino & Camillo Costantini, ‘On some questions about $KC$ and related spaces’, freely available [here](http://hdl.handle.net/2318/391) as a PDF. I quote the example here:

> $\bf{3.4.}$ **Example.** Let $\tau$ be the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$ and $\tau'$ the restriction of $\tau$ to $Y=[0,+\infty[\;\cap\Bbb Q$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p,p_1,p_2\}$ where $p,p_1,p_2$ are three distinct elements not belonging to $Y$. Consider the topology $\sigma$ on $X$ such that $\sigma\upharpoonright_Y=\tau'$, the point $p$ has the fundamental system of (open) neighbourhoods $$\big\{\{p\}\cup\big(Y\setminus(K\cup\Bbb N)\big)\mid K\text{ is a compact subset of }(Y,\tau')\big\}$$ (where $\Bbb N=\omega\setminus\{0\}$), while each of the points $p_i$ for $i=1,2$ has the fundamental system of (open) neighbourhoods $$\{V_{i,\varphi,n}\mid\varphi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N, n\in\Bbb N\}\;,$$ where $$V_{i,\varphi,n}=\{p_i\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n'\ge n}\bigg(\Big]n'-\frac1{\varphi(n')+1},n'+\frac1{\varphi(n')+1}\Big[\cap\Bbb Q\bigg)\setminus\Bbb N\right)$$ for every $\varphi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ and every $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $(X,\sigma)$ is a $KC$ space which is not Katětov $KC$.

The proof is a bit over a page in length, so I’ll not give it here.